# MySQL Query for dates that have not been picked by a customer

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, cross-join

I am using mySQL to build an application where a customer can pick available dates.

I want two queries, one that specifies what slots each customer picked and one the specifies which date has not yet been picked.

**The setup**

I have a list of time slots in the form of dates

```
TABLE: timeslots

slot_id | date
1       | 2020-10-01
2       | 2020-10-02
3       | 2020-10-03
```

I also have a customer table

```
TABLE: customers

customer_id | name
1           | Anders
2           | Joe
3           | Karen
```

Each customer can pick whatever date they like which is specified in the customer_timeslot table which has two Foreign Keys.

```
TABLE: customer_timeslot

customer_id | slot_id
1           | 1
1           | 2
2           | 1
3           | 1
```

**First query all good**

The first query is easy enough and gives me the dates Anders has picked.

The query for the dates Anders (cust. 1) picked

```
SELECT timeslots.date AS Date, customer.name AS Customer FROM timeslots 
JOIN customer_timeslot
USING (slot_id)
JOIN customers
USING (customer_id)
WHERE customers.customer_id = 1
```

Result query 1

```
Date       | Customer
2020-10-01 | Anders
2020-10-02 | Anders
```

**The result I want for the second query**

I want the date Anders has not picked yet which would look like this

```
Date       | Customer
2020-10-03 | Anders
```

**What I've tried**

I've tried to use LEFT JOIN instead of JOIN..

```
SELECT timeslots.date AS Date, customer.name AS Customer FROM timeslots 
LEFT JOIN customer_timeslot
USING (slot_id)
JOIN customers
USING (customer_id)
WHERE customers.customer_id = 1
```

..Which i expected would give me this result but instead gives me the exact same as the INNER JOIN (No NULL to work with)

```
Date       | Customer
2020-10-01 | Anders
2020-10-02 | Anders
2020-10-03 | NULL
```

How can i get the desired query? Shouldn't be so complicated I guess but I'm finding myself completely stuck and looking for some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from timeslots t
where not exists (
    select 1
    from customer_timeslot ct
    where ct.customer_id = 1 and ct.slot_id = t.slot_id
)
```

This returns the timeslots that `customer_id` `1` did not pick. You can get the information for all customers at once with a `cross join`, then `not exists`:

```
select t.date, c.name
from timeslots t
cross join customers c
where not exists (
    select 1
    from customer_timeslot ct
    where ct.customer_id = c.customer_id and ct.slot_id = t.slot_id
)
```